# Get server information in Oracle

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle10g, cpu-usage

I have a project written in C# used Oracle database v10.2.0.3, there's about 10 or more clients run the program
I want to find a way to know all the information from server (RAM, CPU usage... like task manager in windows)  for each session login to database from clients to make a report

Is there any idea?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ?

Comment: It's just a simple project using ODP.Net to connect to Oracle database with some tables, nothing more, it's just i want to make some report from client, to test the performance, that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

[V$SESSMETRIC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2097.htm#I1030339) may have the information you're looking for:

```
select *
from v$sessmetric
order by physical_reads desc, logical_reads desc, cpu desc, pga_memory desc;
```

Results are ordered by the columns that are usually the most important; IO is generally more important than CPU.

If you need more information, you may want to look at [V$SESSTAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2098.htm).